# Change UIButton text on click

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I have button named "Delete" which removes cell from list. When I click on that button I want my botton to be renamed as "Done" which completes the edit.. Help me.

Comment: have you tried to... read the `UIButton` Class Reference ever? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self.btn setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

    - (IBAction)deleteBtn:(id)sender
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        //Do your delete action here;    
    }completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [self.btn setTitle:@"done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     }];

}
```

Comment: after changing the title to "Done", is it ever show "Delete" on the button title ? i think no, because in your code "Delete" is written in only viewdidload.

Comment: Requirement like this only right. What he mention after tapping "Delete" button my button need to be renamed as "Done".

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.btn setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (IBAction)deleteBtn:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        //Do your delete action here;    
    }completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        [sender setTitle:@"done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }];
}
```